# Как получить имя параметра маршрута Express?

Tags: node.js, express

Каким образом можно получить имя параметра в маршруте Express?

Имею к примеру маршрут `'/user/:userId'`
При переходе получаю динамический адрес `/user/5af2fe6cc7a7631ae040db43`.

Хочу сделать промежуточный обработчик который будет выбирать информацию о маршруте из БД. Найти в БД динамический адрес не получится без преобразования `5af2fe6cc7a7631ae040db43` в `/:` и поиск соответствия `/user/:`.

Такой скрипт я сделал, но мне интересно есть ли способ полегче, тем более, что скрипт работает только с 1 параметром, то есть к примеру `/user/:username/:userId` он пока не сможет обработать (надо допилить).

```
// Moongose
var Routes = mongoose.model('Routes', RoutesSchema);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
//Получаем информацию о маршруте из бд
Routes.find({'path' : req.originalUrl}, (err, pageInfo) => {
    // Если документ не найден
    if(pageInfo == null) {
        var search = req.originalUrl.split('/');
        search.splice(-1,1,':');
        search = search.join('/');
        // serach =  /user/:
        Routes.findOne({'path' : {$regex: search}}, function(err, pageInfo) {
            // Устанавливаем локальные переменные ответа
            res.locals.title = pageInfo.title;
            res.locals.description = pageInfo.description;
            next()
        })
    }
    // Если все ок
    else {
        // Устанавливаем локальные переменные ответа
        res.locals.title = pageInfo.title
        res.locals.description= pageInfo.description
        next()
      }
   })
})
```

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Ээээ? `req.params.userId` не работает что ли?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, в промежуточном обработчике нет req.params, точнее если использовать app.use(function(req, res, next) {})

Comment: А мы должны что у вас за промежуточный обработчик? Код в студию

Comment: @AlexeyTen, добавил пример кода для наглядности

Comment: А зачем вы храните роуты в базе??? Ну хорошо, пусть в базе, но проще же при инициализации приложения достать роуты из базы и создать нормальные middleware

Comment: @AlexeyTen В базе хранится заголовок, описание и т.п. Данные из бд я планирую потом вынести из базы в переменную, что бы уменьшить количество запросов к базе. Меня больше интересует, как можно получить имя параметра, да бы не приводить к виду /user/:id...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77348/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and--).

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть обект req, у него есть обект params у которого записано все параметры с адреса.
Пример:

```
/api/device/:id/:additionalParam/:kokoko

/api/device/275/lalala/3ab

req.params.id == 275

req.params.additionalParam == lalala

req.params.kokoko == 3ab
```

Comment: В промежуточном обработчике нет req.params